# Import related error, simple program

Tags: python, class, import, traceback

Okay, so I friend of mine asked me to help with this little program. I can't really code anything, tried coding Python a bit last year. So when I try to run the program it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Python33/program.py", line 38, in module
      import example1
ImportError: No module named 'example1'
```

Here's the program:

---

```
class example1:



    def __init__(self, nopeus, halkaisija, vari, paalla):
        self.__nopeus = nopeus
        self.__halkaisija = halkaisija
        self.__vari = vari
        self.__paalla = paalla

    def set_nopeus(self, nopeus):
        self.__nopeus = 'nopeus'

    def set_halkaisija(self, halkaisija):
        self.__halkaisija = 'halkaisija'

    def set_vari(self, vari):
        self.__vari = 'vari'

    def set_paalla(self, paalla):
        self.__paalla = 'paalla'

    def get_nopeus(self):
        return self.__nopeus

    def get_halkaisija(self):
        return self.__halkaisija

    def get_vari(self):
        return self.__vari

    def get_paalla(self):
        return self.__paalla



import Example1

def main():
    oma_example1 = example1.Example1()
    print (oma_puhallin.get_nopeus)

main()
```

Comment: doesnt matter he is trying to import when he is in the same file as the class

Comment: Note that using two leading underscores (`__foo`) for class member names will trigger [name mangling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/1599111), which is most likely not the desired behavior if you plan to subclass `Puhallin`.

Comment: @LukasGraf ... since they are all have getter/setters I would assume that is the desired behaviour (closest thing to private variables python has)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import Puhallin

def main():
    oma_puhallin = Puhallin("nopeus", "halkaisija", "vari", "paalla")
    print (oma_puhallin.get_nopeus() ) #this is a method not a variable

main()
```

you dont need to import if you are in the same file

Comment: Now it says: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/program.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python33/program.py", line 41, in main
    oma_puhallin = puhallin.Puhallin()
NameError: global name 'puhallin' is not defined

Comment: yeah my bad ... forgot to get rid of that ... now its fixed

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'nopeus', 'halkaisija', 'vari', and 'paalla' that's what it says now.

Comment: it takes arguments in its init method (that you apparently defined) ... (edited my answer to include them?) ...